# how to update properties of item in doc set with client object model

Tags: 2010, development, client-object-model, document-set

I've been able to create doc sets and upload files to it with the client object model. I am having difficulty updating the properties of the files in the doc sets. Here is what I've tried:

```
    public void UploadDocument(string siteurl, string listname, string docsetname, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File filename, string destination)
        {

            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteurl))
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"); 
                //Get Document List
                List documentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(listname));

                clientContext.Load(filename);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                var xfile = destination + filename.Name;

                #region
                //filename.CopyTo(xfile, true);
                //clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                //Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileInformation fileInformation = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, filename.ServerRelativeUrl);
                //Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, destination, fileInformation.Stream, true);
                #endregion

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, xfile, 
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, filename.ServerRelativeUrl).Stream, true);


//==============>this is my problem area <====================

                List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Personnel Files2");

                CamlQuery cq = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
                ListItemCollection personFilesL =  oList.GetItems(cq);

                clientContext.Load(oList);
                clientContext.Load(personFilesL);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                var liItem = personFilesL.ToList().Select(c => c.FieldValues["Name"] == filename.Name); //.Where(c => c.FieldValues["Name"] == filename.Name).Select(c => c.FieldValues["id"]);
                ListItem li = oList.GetItems(liItem); //.GetItemById(liItem);

                li["Document_x0020_Type"] = "Personnel file";
                li["Country0"] = "1;#China";
                li.Update();


//=================> end problem area <=======================
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            }
        }
```

What is the best way to update the properties of the files?

Answer (score 1):

A search for the same answr brought me to your (old) question. I found the answer and thought i'd share it with you.
I code in VB.NET and i converted my code to your C# syntax. Replace your problem area with this code. That should probably do the trick.

```
File pfile = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(xfile);
pfile.CheckOut();
ListItem li = File.ListItemAllFields;
li["Document_x0020_Type"] = "Personnel file";
li["Country0"] = "1;#China";
pfile.Update();
pfile.CheckIn("", CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this few lines of code.

```
// Update the Metadata for the uploaded file in to the Document Set
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File oFile =  oRootWeb.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("Server relative url of the file");
oFile.ListItemAllFields["Migrated"] = true; 
oFile.ListItemAllFields["Author"] = sSystemAccount;
oFile.ListItemAllFields["Editor"] = sSystemAccount;
oFile.ListItemAllFields["Created"] = oAttachment.DateModified;
oFile.ListItemAllFields["Modified"] = oAttachment.DateModified;
oFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```